# Include rows from multiple dataframes into a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have around 20 dataframes where I am targeting values of a specific row. For example, I'm showing a simplified version of one of my dataframe

```
    Type   N1   N2
    43     121  455
    23     554  52
    85     74   615
```

I want to get the row of every "Type" 23 from my datasets

I have tried the code given below but the output is some trash.

```
dataf = pd.DataFrame()
for x in [df1,df2,...df20]:
    data = x.loc[x['Type']==23]
dataf.append(data)
```

What I expect to have is a new dataframe with same columns as N1 and N2 with the values of the selected rows.

The expected new dataframe:

```
    N1   N2
    554  52
    153  87  and so on..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to combine the data frames prior to filtering:

```
dfc = pd.concat([df1, df2, ..., df20])
dataf = dfc[dfc.Type == 23][['N1', 'N2']]
```

Depending a bit on what your pipeline looks like, chances are that you can combine the data frames already when they're read in the first place.

Comment: Doing the filtering before the `concat` could be more efficient.

Comment: @ggrelet can you explain filtering?

Comment: I added my own response because of the formatting limits of Comments compared to Answers. Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

I think that:

```py
df_list = [df1,df2, ...,df20]
filtered_df_list = [ df[df['Type'] == 23] for df in df_list ] #Filter each mini-df on "Type" = 23

final_df = pd.concat(filtered_df_list) # Concat the small mini-dfs (hence faster concatenating)
```

Could be more efficient and less time-consuming depending on the size of the dataframes, but that could be proven. If you share with us some data so I can do it, or if you want to do it yourself, I'm interested in the answer.